# Xcode 8.2 Mfmailcompose

Tags: ios, swift, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm making a simple app that needs the end user to be able to message me for comments, suggestions and what have you.  I've looked and looked and couldn't come up with anything.

I running Xcode 8.2 and when I run my simulator to bring up the mailcomposeview it crashes with a "Thread1: siganl SIGABRT".  I'm stuck and can't figure out why it keeps crashing.

Here's the code I have written. Again, I am new and could be overlooking something that maybe someone will spot off the bat.

```
@IBAction func sendEmail(_ sender: Any) {
    if !MFMailComposeViewController.canSendMail() {
        print("Try Again, Check your mail prefences")
    }
    let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self

    composeVC.setToRecipients(["atittle223@gmail.com"])
    composeVC.setSubject("")
    composeVC.setMessageBody("Message here", isHTML: true)

    self.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)

    func mailComposeViewController(controller: MFMailComposeViewController, didFinishWith: MFMailComposeResult, error: NSError?){
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the crash? Why do you let the method continue even if you can't send email? Why is the delegate method nested inside the `sendMail` function?